# Shorter code for this JavaScript "if" statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Is there a short way to write the following using either JavaScript or jQuery?

```
if (this.id==="a" || this.id==="b" || this.id==="c" || this.id==="d")
```

Comment: Here's a page to compare the performance of various suggestions below: http://jsperf.com/set-memberbship

Comment: @Jason LeBrun I have a +1 for the nice demo -- but as [more-often-then-not] always, *clarity first*. I blame my CPU for the slow FF posting ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ( ['a','b','c','d'].indexOf( this.id ) >= 0 ) { ... }
```

or

```
if ( this.id in {'a':0,'b':0,'c':0,'d':0} ) { ... }
```

Comment: If `this.id` is `'a'`, the first example wouldn't know it.

Comment: Both your @limc's amswer (d in o) are similar and fastest way to write it. Thanks for the performance link you provided.

Comment: @alex: You'll probably want the `in` version if you need wide browser support since `indexOf` doesn't have as much cross-browser support.

Comment: In fact you could probably shorten up the `in` version a bit by getting rid of the quotation marks around the property names in the object. As long as the IDs are valid javascript identifiers, you don't need em.

Answer (score 6):

How about this?

```
if ( this.id in { "a":1, "b":1, "c":1, "d":1 } ) {
  ...
}
```

<s>... or this?</s>

```
if("abcd".indexOf(this.id) > -1) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: **+1** I probably wouldn't use `1` as the dummy value, though.

Comment: @ClosureCowboy: Thanks for the tip... I also added another example, although it is really not that readable in my opinion. :)

Comment: i wouldn't combine all lettere as one word. This will not work if the variable is more then 1 letter, although it is a nice way to write it.

Comment: And here I was writing out the array. Silly me.

Comment: @Alex: you are right, I strike it out... @Jason, :D ... I give you +1 for throwing the array brackets at me. :)

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is a switch statement.

```
switch(this.id){case"a":case"b":case"c":case"d":
    //do something
}
```

Comment: that works too but we end up repeating the word case 4 times just as in my example repeating the word this.id 4 times.

Comment: @alex: Yes it does, but it is a bit shorter, so I thought I'd throw it out there. :o)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code. Especially when you have more than four test values.

```
if (/^[abcdef]$/.test(this.id)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: How about if the variable is more then one letter.

Comment: `if(/^(val1|val2|val3)$/.test(this.id)) { ... }`

Comment: Updated the test script to include these two ideas as well.

Answer (score 0):

The inline anonymous hash (`d in o`) performance was misrepresented in the [tests as originally written](http://jsperf.com/set-memberbship/), because the hash wasn't inline in the test.

Oddly enough, the true inline hash case, compared to the predefined hash case, is *much slower* in Firefox 4, but *50% faster* in Chrome 12.

But a more important point is that `d in o` misses the point of a hash—that you don't have to iterate to find things.

Two lines, but still pretty short, and [by far the fastest](http://jsperf.com/set-memberbship/5):

```
var o = {a:1,b:1,c:1,d:1};
if(o[this.id]){...}
```